# can't get number from NSArrayM

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, int

i get the below error when trying to retrieve a key name from a query.  and then cast it as an int of use by viewcontroller.

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1073ebdb0) to 'NSNumber' (0x1069f3488).
```

this is the line in the query:

```
tempVarLDS = object.value(forKey: keyName)
```

when printed this returns

```
(
  7
)
```

so it is an array.  but i can't seem to access it via

```
tempvarLDS[0]
```

or any of the usual suspects.  any idea how to get this int?

Comment: What happened when you tried `tempvarLDS[0]`?

Comment: Why are you using `NSArray` instead of a Swift array?

Comment: it is the result of a parse query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an NSArray of NSNumbers, you should be able to cast it as an array of integers.

```
// Cast it
let tempvarLDS:[Int] = object.value(forKey: keyName) as! [Int]

// Loop
for num in tempvarLDS {
    print(num)
}
```

I don't see why that wouldn't work

Comment: Certainly! Glad to help.